# Rename the URL'name in React Router Breadcrumb component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, breadcrumbs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to build a Dynamic Breadcrumb React component that detects my location on the website and show it.
This is the code I've tried from this [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9kn8yQPC4E):

```
import React from “react”;
import {
  Breadcrumbs as MUIBreadcrumbs,
  Link,
  Typography
} from “@material-ui/core”;
import { withRouter } from “react-router-dom”;

const Breadcrumbs = props => {
  const {
    history,
    location: { pathname }
  } = props;
  const pathnames = pathname.split(“/”).filter(x => x);
  return (
    <MUIBreadcrumbs aria-label=“breadcrumb”>
      {pathnames.length > 0 ? (
        <Link onClick={() => history.push(“/”)}>Home</Link>
      ) : (
        <Typography> Home </Typography>
      )}
      {pathnames.map((name, index) => {
        const routeTo = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join(“/”)}`;
        const isLast = index === pathnames.length - 1;
        return isLast ? (
          <Typography key={name}>{name}</Typography>
        ) : (
          <Link key={name} onClick={() => history.push(routeTo)}>
            {name}
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </MUIBreadcrumbs>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Breadcrumbs);
```

This code works well with me but I want the breadcrumb to show a specific text when it reaches to a page, for example if the url for the about page is '/about' and I want to show it on breadcrumb as 'About Us' like this:

> Home / About Us

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the name of the URL and if it matches 'about' you could say it should give 'About Us' as an output. This is probably not a 100% perfect solution but it would work like this:

```
{pathnames.map((name, index) => {
  const routeTo = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join("/")}`;
  const isLast = index === pathnames.length - 1;
  return isLast ? (
    <Typography key={name}>
      { // change this line to this: }
      {name === "about" ? "About Us" : name}
    </Typography>
  ) : (
  <Link key={name} onClick={() => history.push(routeTo)}>
    {name}
  </Link>
  );
})}
```

If the path is 'about' it would show 'About Us' instead of about. And for any other case it would output the pathname.

If you want to do it for multiple pages you could create an object (In this case I called it 'pages') where the key is the pathname and then assign the value you want to it. Like this:

```
{pathnames.map((name, index) => {
  const routeTo = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join("/")}`;
  const isLast = index === pathnames.length - 1;
  const pages = { 'about': 'About Us', 'contact': 'Contact Us' };
  return isLast ? (
    <Typography key={name}>
      {pages[name]}
    </Typography>
  ) : (
    <Link key={name} onClick={() => history.push(routeTo)}>
      {name}
    </Link>
  );
})}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but if I want it for more other pages like 'contact us' and 'our services' pages.. how?

Comment: You could create an Object with the pathname as key and then just add the value you want to it. I added an example to my answer.